# Saving and loading custom models with BatchNormalization layers in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, batch-normalization

I am training a custom model that includes `BatchNormalization` layers in TensorFlow 2.12. Along training, I save some checkpoints like this:

```
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(0), optimizer=optimizer, model=model)
manager    = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint, os.path.join(output_folder,"ckpts"), max_to_keep=3)
manager.save(checkpoint_number=int(checkpoint.step)+1)
```

After the model is trained, I load the checkpoints like this

```
checkpoint.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint).expect_partial()
```

The weights are loaded into the model successfully. However, the non-trainable variables `moving_variance` and `moving_mean` of the `BatchNormalization` layers are reset to their default values, 1 and 0 respectively.

Why are the checkpoints not saving the values of `moving_variance` and `moving_mean` calculated during training?